# warning: 'UIAlertView' may not respond to '-addTextFieldWithValue:label:'

Tags: iphone

in my application i was using UIAlertView for login, it contains TextFields, its working perfectly, but i'm getting a warning when i compile the code, i'm using iphone SDK 3.0

code :

```
loginAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter the User Name and Password" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Login", nil];
  
[loginAlert addTextFieldWithValue:appDelegate.userName label:@"UserName"];
```

warning: 'UIAlertView' may not respond to '-addTextFieldWithValue:label:'

```
txfUserName = [loginAlert textFieldAtIndex:0];
```

warning: 'UIAlertView' may not respond to '-textFieldAtIndex:'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your title here!" message:@"this gets covered" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
[myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[myAlertView addSubview:testTextField];
CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 130.0);
[myAlertView setTransform:myTransform];
[myAlertView show];
[myAlertView release];
```

all credits to: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1704-uitextfield-inside-uialertview.html

Comment: Its working, but there is an initial delay, not as perfect as the private method, thank you for the valuable information

Comment: you may create the view on the containing UIViewController class initialization and release it when the view unloads, so the delay is masked by the transition.

Answer (score 3):

This method is private, you should not use it (your app will be rejected). Maybe they removed or renamed it in the latest SDK. For an alternative, see

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/alert-view-with-prompt.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://github.com/enormego/EGOTextFieldAlertView. It gives you those private methods, in a subclass of `UIAlertView`. This way you don't have to change your code at all.

Comment: Apple uses an automated static analyzer; the app will still be rejected because the method is named the same, I think.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not the case: to my knowledge, enormego (the creator of that class) did publish some apps with `EGOTextFieldAlertView`.

Comment: Strange, I've heard of apps rejected because of a private method name. Good to know.

Comment: EGOTextFieldAlertView changes the names of the methods it has to make them different from the private methods